# How can I add required columns in odoo Many2many form view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I am having a Many2many field on a form view, field is supposed to show 5 columns but it shows only 3 in my case. All 5 fields are available there on other model. but still not able to get the solution. Help appreciated. I am using Odoo v-10.

[Here it shows 3 columns, and I want 5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgeEZ.png)

Comment: This is some simple logic to do , even it is present in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit its form view and where you defined the field add its view there

```xml
<field name="my_many2many_field">
    <tree>
        <field name="first_field"/>
        <field name="second_field"/>
        <field name="third_field"/>
        <field name="fourth_field"/>
        <field name="fifth_field"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: <field name="you_field_name">
<tree>
<field name="first_field"/>
<field name="first_field"/>
<field name="first_field"/>
<field name="first_field"/>
<field name="first_field"/>
</tree>
</field>

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply!
but. it giving another error,

ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `product_id` does not exist

Comment: in first_field place put the field name of model which your one2many has relationship